# How would one select text out of nested html elements using waitForKeyElements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, tampermonkey

I attempted to write a tampermonkey script that would watch a dynamic page that updates via Ajax every time a new comment is submitted.  I want to select [USERNAME] and [USER COMMENT] from each entry as it comes in.  I've been tinkering with waitForKeyElements, but I was having trouble pulling the data from the respective elements.

The block of html below is what gets appended to the page as each user submits their comments where [USERNAME] and [USER COMMENT] are random usernames and comments that come in sporadically.  As each of the two fields come in, I'd like to capture the name with it's respective comment.

```
<div data-name="[USERNAME]">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div ts="Av" data-listener-count-click="1" data-listener-count-contextmenu="1">
                [USERNAME]
                <span class="myclass_username" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="https://myserver.com/images/icon.svg" height="10" width="10">
                </span>
            </div>
        <span class="emoticonImage"> [USER COMMENT]</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you try using regex?  What do you want to do with their two fields once they are "captured"?

Comment: I may try regex next, I was just hoping there was a more elegant way to pull the data from the elements without resorting to regex.  I'm looking to capture the username and comment so that I can then search the comments for key words and act on certain words as they come in via Ajax.  So if someone mentioned my name, I could have my Tampermonkey userscript fire off a command to a raspberry pi to blink a light on my desk.  (that's just a simple use case that I want to expand into other areas)